# Save CheckBox state to xml

Tags: c#, wpf

My application is a form based application, having multiple textboxes that can be filled. Some textboxes however is optional and a checkbox is included to toggle if it should be included.

Now I would like to save the progress of the form so it can be opened later for further editing. I am saving this file as an `.xml`. Saving the textboxes I have no problem with, but what is the best way to save the state of the checkboxes to the `.xml` file, so it can be loaded later?

I can simply use - `string s = Bool.ToString();`.
It does work but when working with a lot of checkboxes it can become a long process. I have a `class` that handles the saving of the `.xml` file. Is there a way to add more then one checkbox to a list then parse the `"true/false"` value to the class as an array of `Bool[]`?

Comment: I would use a boolean.

Comment: You can use the "true"/"false" boolean value.

Comment: Create a proper Serializable DataModel and use the `DataContractSerializer` or even the `XmlSerializer`.

Answer (score 3):

Checkbox-state is nothing else than an Boolean? -> Nullable bool. You can simple serialize it using an xmlserializer or write it manually to the file:

```
string s = checked.ToString();
```

and to parse it:

```
bool checked = Boolean.Parse(s)
```